# error when i will generate insight in SHAP with an SVM model

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, shap

I made some models and SHAP worked normally with random forest, but with this one I already defined

```
 df_new = SVC(kernel="poly", random_state=1, C=3.0)
 df_new.fit(x_train, y_train)

 previsoes = df_new.predict(x_test)
 previsoes

 explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(df_new)
 shap_values = explainer.shap_values(x)
 shap.summary_plot(shap_values, x)

 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-84-58995882eb99> in <module>
  1 #Explanando as influências das variáveis na predição (SVM)  2 explainer = 
  shap.KernelExplainer(previsoes)
  3 shap_values = explainer.shap_values(x)
  4 shap.summary_plot(shap_values, x)

  TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

Answer (score 0):

[shap.KernelExplainer](https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.KernelExplainer.html) has two required parameters: model and data. So you need to include ***data*** in your method and also pass *previsoes* instead of the model (*df_new*), for example:

```
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(previsoes, x_train)
```